# Checking a rails API request comes from JS assets

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I want to call some API methods of my rails app using JS from within the same app's assets (using jquery/ajax) so that I can call controller methods from within my JS, but I don't want those API methods to be accessible by anybody, just my JS.

Is there an easy way to confirm that the request comes from my JS or do I have to use something like a secret token?

I'm also using the JS to do things like create entries in my db and search for entries, so let me know if I'm improperly making my JS try to do things I should be doing with model/controller logic. (I'm only using JS right now because I need to send messages and responses to an iframe calling the app.)

Comment: You won't ever be able to lock something down by your javascript, because anyone can look at what your javascript is doing.  If you want to prevent others from using the API, you can do this by locking calls down by domain.

Comment: Sorry about the late response, I ended up moving to another problem before coming back. You were right--I ended up learning that browsers restrict such cross-domain requests automatically, so I just added the ajax call. I actually have a follow up question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30881468/security-vulnerabilities-in-ajax-call-to-rails-app-with-a-dash-of-iframe-on-the), if you're interested.